# If string contains statement - Swift 2 Xcode 7

Tags: ios, if-statement, contains, swift2, xcode7-beta5

I am using the Xcode 7 beta 5 and Swift 2. I currently have a UITextField and a UIButton. The UITextField is set to a decimal pad, but however, the user is able to enter in multiple decimals. That is not how I would like the app to work. I would like to check, when the button is tapped, if the text field has 0-1 decimal points. Is there any statement that checks for multiple decimal points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `textField` with a reference to your UITextField in this:

```
   if textField.text.componentsSeperatedByString(".").count >= 3 {
          // more than 1 decimal point
    }
```

This seperates the text in the text field into an array and creates an array of strings separated on any decimal points. If there are 0-1 decimal points, the array will have less than 3 items. [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString:) documentation might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Give the text field a [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:) and implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to prevent the user from entering a decimal point if there is already one present.

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't really work for me. Could you please try to be more specific? I tried entering in both pieces of code, but they didn't work...